# Fitting as many divs as possible horizontally in HTML, and filling the line width

Tags: html, css

I have a bunch of fixed-width `div` elements styled to flow inline using `inline-block` display type. This leaves an empty space at the end of the line (where the next `div` could not be fitted and wrapped to the next line).

What I'd like to do, is to expand all of the divs on the row evenly to fill up the row, **similar to the "Justify" alignment for the text**.

In other words, I want to have a minimum width on `div` elements and fit as many of them as possible in a single row, and fill the entire row.

Here's my sample HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #container { margin: 100px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid blue; }
        .item { margin: 10px; width: 300px; min-width: 300px; display: inline-block; border: 1px solid red; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="item">Item One</div>
        <div class="item">Item Two</div>
        <div class="item">Item Three</div>
        <div class="item">Item Four</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is that possible with pure CSS + HTML? Or do I have to write a script to achieve this result?

---

UPDATE: Since people keep suggesting to use percentage widths to fit items in a single row, I have to note that it's NOT the intention of this question. I want to have something like "Justified" text, but with blocks. Number of items are variable, and can be too many.

The blocks need to be the same size, have a default (minimum) width that will cause them to wrap to next line if needed, and the container's width is needed to be filled with child items by extending their width.

---

UPDATE 2:

Current sample produces something like this:

```
|--------------------------- Container -----------------------------|
| |------ 1 ------| |------ 2 ------| |------ 3 ------|             |
| |------ 4 ------| |------ 5 ------| |------ 6 ------|             |
| |------ 7 ------|                                                 |
```

I'm looking to see something like this:

```
|---------------------------- Container ----------------------------|
| |-------- 1 --------| |-------- 2 --------| |-------- 3 --------| |
| |-------- 4 --------| |-------- 5 --------| |-------- 6 --------| |
| |-------- 7 --------|                                             |
```

Or this:

```
|---------------------------- Container ----------------------------|
| |-------- 1 --------| |-------- 2 --------| |-------- 3 --------| |
| |-------- 4 --------| |-------- 5 --------| |-------- 6 --------| |
| |------------------------------ 7 ------------------------------| |
```

Each item has a minimum size, so in the above example item #4 and #7 won't fit the remaining space on the line and would wrap to the next line. I want the ones already fitted to the line to fill up the space.

Note that the container may re-size because the browser can be re-sized. So, if it becomes smaller to the extent that only two items fit in a row, I'd want to see something like this:

```
|----------------- Container -----------------|
| |-------- 1 --------| |-------- 2 --------| |
| |-------- 3 --------| |-------- 4 --------| |
| |-------- 5 --------| |-------- 6 --------| |
| |------------------- 7 -------------------| |
```

I hope this clears the intent of the question.

Comment: Using CSS, set the div tags width as a percentage.

Comment: I've already tried this. It does not yield the expected results. The number of `div` elements in a row is variable, and changes depending the container (browser window) width.

Comment: I have no idea if this works, but since inline-block reacts to line-height, letter-spacing and text-align: center, perhaps you could simply use text-align: justify?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this with the [flexbox model](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox/#intro), there are some issues though.

There is an old and a new flexbox model, which does make things kind of complicated. Currently only [Chrome and Opera](http://caniuse.com/flexbox) support the new model, and other browsers have "Partial support", which means that they might be supporting:

1. An [older version of the w3 specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-css3-flexbox-20090723/)
2. An [older syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-flexbox-20120322/)
3. Or they just haven't gotten around to fully implementing the new or even the old model yet

With whatever is available today I was able to put something together which works in **Chrome 26**, **Safari 5.1.7**, **IE10**, **IE10 in IE9 mode** and **IE10 in IE8 mode**. Sadly, my current **Firefox version 20** is not in that list. I am not sure about if it will work in older versions of Firefox (I have added the required CSS in the jsFiddle near the bottom of the post, but I don't have any older versions installed on my PC).

This [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/flex-wrap) explains why it does not work in **Firefox 20**. If you scroll down to the bottom of the page, it states about the `flex-wrap` property:

> Firefox (Gecko) - Not Supported. Firefox supports only single-line flexbox.

I'm not 100% sure about this, but it seems to me that they have never supported the `flex-wrap` property even in older versions. Correct me if I'm wrong, to anyone with a **Firefox 19-** version out there, but I think if they had, **Firefox 20** would at least fall back on it for as long as they have not yet fully implemented the new flexbox model.

This `flex-wrap` property is the one that makes the multi-line magic happen in most of the other browsers. <strike>The forecast is that **Firefox** will be [fully supporting the new flexbox model in version 22](http://caniuse.com/flexbox), which is [scheduled to be released on June 25, 2013](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Firefox#Version_22).</strike> **UPDATE:** [Firefox now does support](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=948654) the `flex-wrap` property [from version 28 upwards.](http://blog.dholbert.org/2013/12/multi-line-flexbox-support-in-nightly.html) **/UPDATE**

After all that, here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Xr5K/3) which does the job as well as possible, according to my recent research. This seems to be the best you can do in pure CSS + HTML with the current browser support.

If you want something better **right now**, you would have to come up with a JS solution. Maybe have a look at the source of [flexieJS](https://github.com/doctyper/flexie) and modify the browser detection code so that it will handle **Firefox 20** as well. `box-pack` and `box-orient` are on the list of supported properties of FlexieJS, they are the properties that are making this work on older **iOS** and **Safari**.

**Edit:** As @Cimmanon points out in the comments, to get this to work in older browsers they would need to support `box-lines: multiple`, which they don't. So this isn't going to work on older versions of **iOS**, **Safari** and **Firefox**. I guess this explains why **Firefox 20** does not have an old implementation to fall back on. Since FlexieJS does not have support for `box-lines: multiple` either, its source is probably not going to be of much help with trying to fix this issue. Writing your own JS fix seems to be the only **right now** solution. The developer of FlexieJS has been working on a [polyfill for the new specification](https://github.com/doctyper/reflexie/branches). This would have to include some code to fix the multiline in older browsers. It does not look like there is any at the moment though. If you're going to write something, maybe you could contact him for some insights. Pass him your code if you get it working. If you are lucky he has got something going already which isn't up on GitHub yet.

The CSS:

```
#container {
  margin: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: -webkit-box;     /* iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  display: -moz-box;        /* Firefox 19- */
  display: -ms-flexbox;     /* IE 10 */
  display: -webkit-flex;    /* Chrome */
  display: flex;            /* Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */

  /* iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-lines: multiple;  /* Only here for informative purpose, this line is what should have made it work, it has never been implemented */ 

  /* Firefox 19- */
  -moz-flex-flow: row wrap;
  -moz-justify-content: space-between;
  -moz-box-lines: multiple; /* Only here for informative purpose, this line is what should have made it work, it has never been implemented */ 

  /* Chrome */
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;

  /* IE10 */
  -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
  -ms-justify-content: space-between;

  /* Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.item {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  -webkit-box-flex: auto;    /* iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  -moz-box-flex: 1.0;        /* Firefox 19- */
  -webkit-flex: auto;        /* Chrome */
  -ms-flex: auto;            /* IE10 */
  flex: auto;                /* Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
}
```

Comment: There's a lot of "information" here to make your answer look impressive, but it isn't reflected in your provided CSS.  Because no browser implements `box-lines: multiple` (necessary for wrapping in the 2009 spec), it is going to end up broken in half the browsers you've provided prefixes/properties for.

Comment: Thanks or the info, I guess it explains why Firefox 20 does not have an older implementation to fall back on.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info. IE10 behaves exactly as I expect, that's cool. But I finally decided not to use such cutting-edge specification for the time being, as my end users are not so up-to-date! But it's good to be aware of this "flexbox model".

Answer (score 1):

You can do this two ways (if you know how many .items there are):

**Example one:**
Floating the .items works, see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/David_Knowles/wh5bP/

```
#container { 
    margin: 100px; 
    overflow:hidden;
    border: 1px solid blue; 
}
.item { 
    width: 23%; /* important: (100% / numberOfItems - margin%) */
    margin: 0 1%; /* important */
    float:left; /* important */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* only needed to compensate for the border used in your debugging */
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid red;
```

}

**Example Two:**

Inline-block elements are sensitive to the white space between the line breaks. Notice no spaces between the .items. http://jsfiddle.net/David_Knowles/wh5bP/1/

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="item">Item One</div><div class="item">Item Two</div><div class="item">Item Three</div><div class="item">Item Four</div>
</div>

.item { 
    width: 23%;
    margin: 0 1%;
    display:inline-block;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid red;
```

}

If you never know how many .items there will be then you could take a look the flexbox model. 
http://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/
http://caniuse.com/flexbox

If your target audience use IE9 or less then you will need to also use a polyfill.
http://flexiejs.com/

Comment: Where is the minimum size for the items then? I know how to use the percentage sizing. It's not what I'm looking for. Please read the question more carefully. I want each of the items to have a minimum size, and wrap to the next line if they don't fit into one line.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'wrap to next line'. What should wrap to next line; the text inside or the .item? and how wide should that wrapped item now become? A visual sketch might help or your own fiddle.

Comment: Yeap, that explains a lot :-) You are going to need to right some JS to solve this for sure. I'd be interested to see what you come up with.

Comment: If you're presenting Flexbox as a solution *never* use the old Flexbox properties on their own.

Comment: Thanks for the info and effort. Your post is correct and includes good pointers, and it was helpful for me, but I'm marking user1846192's answer as accepted because it has more detailed info and comparisons, for the future readers.

Answer (score 1):

That's a job for Flexbox, but you have to decide on how you want things to lay out for non-Flexbox browsers.  Aligning things to the center might be your best bet.

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/lBDwu

```
ul {
  display: -webkit-flexbox;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  /*  text-align: justify;
    -moz-text-align-last: justify;
    text-align-last: justify;*/
}
@supports (flex-wrap: wrap) {
  ul {
    display: flex;
  }
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-flex: 1 0;
  -ms-flex: 1 0;
  flex: 1 0;
  min-width: 10em;
  background: #CCC;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: .5em;
}
```

Because of the need for wrapping, only Chrome, Opera, and IE10 can do this.  Everyone else is going to receive the fallback experience.

Comment: Thanks for the info and effort. Your post is correct and includes good pointers, and it was helpful for me, but I'm marking user1846192's answer as accepted because it has more detailed info and comparisons, for the future readers.

Comment: Even though user1846192 had the wrong solution and is broken in half the browsers, they get the accept just because it has lots of other information to make it look impressive?  How is that helpful to future readers?  Your question was not a technical question about Flexbox itself, It hardly seems fair to choose the broken solution over one that is correct.