# How to fit as many <div>s as possible horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I have a container `div` that contains many other `div`s. I wish to layout those `div`s into a kind of grid view, where as many `div`s as possible are in each row with equal width. The `div`s have a defined min-width property but not a max-width property.

I found [Fitting as many divs as possible horizontally in HTML, and filling the line width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129657/fitting-as-many-divs-as-possible-horizontally-in-html-and-filling-the-line-widt) but it was different from what I wanted in that what I want doesn't have a fixed number of columns but rather a fixed min-width.

I am trying to make a kind of responsive design-I think I will be using flex box for this, but can't really find any guide to accomplishing what I want. So basically I want to make a flex box with a flexible number of columns based on the min-width of the flex items and screen width.

Any help is appreciated :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the outer div, give it the CSS styles:

```
display:flex;
flex-direction:row;
```

Then for the inner div's, give them the CSS style:

```
min-width: (whatever you want);
```

I've given an example below. However you will of course be better off setting up a class for the outer div, and a class for the inner div, for cleanliness and separation of concerns.

```html
<div style="display:flex;flex-direction:row;">
<div style="min-width:8em;">
hello
</div>
<div style="min-width:8em;">
goodbye
</div>
<div style="min-width:8em;">
one
</div>
<div style="min-width:8em;">
two
</div>
<div style="min-width:8em;">
three
</div>
<div style="min-width:8em;">
four
</div>
<div style="min-width:8em;">
five
</div>
<div style="min-width:8em;">
six
</div>
<div style="min-width:8em;">
seven
</div>
<div style="min-width:8em;">
and so on
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the only answer that actually answers the question. Although I already solved my own problem, accepted for (potential) future viewers. You are the best.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you could do with flex box.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.container>div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #e6e6e6;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px dotted #ababab;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
  <div>13</div>
  <div>14</div>
  <div>15</div>
  <div>16</div>

</div>
```

Comment: I think you did not understand the question very well, or at least not the way I intended-the size of the `div`s should not be specified-only the min-width property should be specified making them scale to fit the screen width.

I want there to be as many divs per row while the divs don't get smaller than their min-width-of course without a horizontal scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>1</div>
  </div>

  .flex-container {
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap; /* Safari */
  flex-wrap:         wrap;
  display: flex;
}
.flex-container > div {
  background: pink;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 0 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This the same as Sreekanth without flex.

The span and div selector can be changed to class selectors for a more generic solution.

```css
.container>div {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #e6e6e6;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px dotted #ababab;
}
.container>span {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
before
<div class="container">

  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
  <div>13</div>
  <div>14</div>
  <div>15</div>
  <div>16</div>

  <span></span>
</div>
after
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all you can add infinite amounts of divs inside a div.. Now, if you want a whole group of divs to equal the 100% width of the parent, you'll need to divide 100% / (#of divs inside the parent), and give that width to every single child (the whole divs inside the parent). In order for this to work properly you'll need to give a "box-sizing: border-box" to the parent and childs. Plus, if you want them "horizontaly align" you have to options:

1. give every single child div the property Float: left;
2. Give every single child div the property Display: Inline-block:

Now, in my opinion that's not the way to go when trying to build a responsive site. There's a few other tricks than "how to fit as many divs as possible horizontally". I think you saw a tutorial were columns are used, but there's a rule of thumb for a reason and that is don't use more than 12 columns in a row. But again, there are better ways to go when trying to make a responsive design.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just ended up using row wrap and flex-grow, at least for now.